# tensor notation in complex geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, tensors

Suppose I have $g$, a symmetric, Hermitian metric on a complex manifold of complex dimension $n$. Can anyone please suggest how to evaluate the following tensorial quantity (assuming Einstein summation convention):

$$g^{\gamma \bar{\delta}}g_{\alpha \bar{\delta}}g_{\bar{\beta} \gamma}$$

where $g^{\gamma \bar{\delta}}$ is the inverse metric of $g$. I was thinking of evaluating this by feeding it vectors i.e. evaluating the quantity

$$g^{\gamma \bar{\delta}}g_{\alpha \bar{\delta}}g_{\bar{\beta} \gamma}u^{\alpha}\bar{u}^{\beta}$$ but there also I am not sure how to calculate this.

Here is what I think : $$g^{\gamma \bar{\delta}}g_{\alpha \bar{\delta}}g_{\bar{\beta} \gamma}u^{\alpha}\bar{u}^{\beta} = g_{\alpha \bar{\beta}}u^{\alpha}\bar{u}^{\beta} = ||u||^2.$$ Please let me know if I am correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am going to switch indices because I want to use $\delta_i^j$ with its standard meaning ($1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise). Second, since the conjugate index should be in the second slot, I'm replacing your third term with $g_{\gamma\bar\beta}$. I will assume this was a typo. Of course, since $g$ is hermitian symmetric, $\overline{g_{\alpha\bar\beta}} = g_{\beta\bar\alpha}$. But a barred index in the first slot is not conventionally defined unless you mean $g_{\bar\beta\alpha} = \overline{g_{\beta\bar\alpha}}=g_{\alpha\bar\beta}$.

So, let's consider $g^{\gamma\bar\sigma}g_{\alpha\bar\sigma}g_{\gamma\bar\beta}$. Since we have
$$g^{\gamma\bar\sigma}g_{\alpha\bar\sigma} = \delta_\alpha^\gamma,$$
it follows that
$$g^{\gamma\bar\sigma}g_{\alpha\bar\sigma}g_{\gamma\bar\beta} = \delta_\alpha^\gamma g_{\gamma\bar\beta} = g_{\alpha\bar\beta}.$$

Then $g^{\gamma\bar\sigma}g_{\alpha\bar\sigma}g_{\gamma\bar\beta}u^\alpha u^{\bar\beta} = g_{\alpha\bar\beta}u^\alpha u^\bar\beta = \langle u,u\rangle = \|u\|^2$, yes.